# Animate element along SVG path on scroll in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, framer-motion

There are relatively straightforward ways of accomplishing this in vanilla Javascript (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608999/moving-image-on-scroll-through-svg-path) for one such approach), but I'm struggling getting something like this to work in React, particularly with an animation library like Framer Motion.

Framer Motion's [useViewPortScroll](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/motionvalue#useviewportscroll) returns a handy scrollYProgress object whose "current" property tells you what percentage down the page the user is currently scrolled.

I'd like to use this property to do something like this: `const pts = path.getPointAtLength(scrollPercentage * pathLength);`, and then use `pts.x` and `pts.y` for the x and y attributes of, say, a circle SVG - so every time I scroll down (or up) the page, the position of the circle would update/animate along the SVG path.

I'm struggling getting this to work with React's more declarative style, as I'd have to use refs for both the circle and the path elements, meaning I would have to place the aforementioned `pts = path.getPointAtLength...` code *inside* of a useEffect call, with both refs as dependencies (or else the refs would be undefined, in which case the `pts.x` and `pts.y` properties on x and y of my circle SVG would be inaccessible on first render.

Has anyone solved a similar problem or could possibly provide guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a simple animation (dot *rotating* around the circle) you could make use of simple [`transform: rotate()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate):

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const ScrollMeter = ({progress=0}) => (
    <svg 
      className="meter"
      style={{transform:`rotate(${360*progress}deg)`}} 
      viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <circle 
        cx="50" 
        cy="50" 
        r="40" 
        fill="none" 
        stroke="gray"
      />
      <circle 
        cx="90"
        cy="50"
        r="10" 
        fill="gray" 
        stroke="white"
      />
    </svg>
) 

const App = () => {
  const [scrollProgress, setScrollProgress] = useState(0),
    onScroll = ({ target: { scrollTop, scrollHeight } }) =>
      setScrollProgress(scrollTop / scrollHeight)
  return (
    <div>
      <ScrollMeter progress={scrollProgress} />
      <div 
        className="scrollArea" 
        onScroll={onScroll}
      >
        { 'there should be some random content here '.repeat(1e3)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, rootNode)
```

```css
.scrollArea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.meter {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

However, if you need something more generic (e.g. for arbitrary shape of trajectory), you may use the same approach as in the post, you're referring to:

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const ScrollMeter = ({progress=0}) => {
  const route = useRef(),
        routeLength = (route.current && route.current.getTotalLength()),
        {x,y} = (route.current ? route.current.getPointAtLength(routeLength*progress) : {x: 90, y:50})
  return (
    <svg className="meter" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle 
        ref={route}
        cx="50" 
        cy="50" 
        r="40" 
        fill="none" 
        stroke="gray"
      />
      <circle 
        cx={x}
        cy={y}
        r="10" 
        fill="gray" 
        stroke="white"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}     

const App = () => {
  const [scrollProgress, setScrollProgress] = useState(0),
    onScroll = ({ target: { scrollTop, scrollHeight } }) =>
      setScrollProgress(scrollTop / scrollHeight)
  return (
    <div>
      <ScrollMeter progress={scrollProgress} />
      <div 
        className="scrollArea" 
        onScroll={onScroll}
      >
        { 'there should be some random content here '.repeat(1e3)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, rootNode)
```

```css
.scrollArea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.meter {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a hard time understanding how to get it to work without the fixed height and overflow auto on the scrollArea element, though. I'd like the animation to occur when the user scrolls the main body, not an inner div with it's own dedicated scroll bar.

Comment: @user11424535 : above code demonstrates the way of attaching `scroll` event to SVG elements attributes. The problem you've just described appears to be different and related to catching *proper* scroll event (for entire document). If you stuck at some point, you may post a separate question describing your problem - comments are not good at all to tackle issues like that.